# Arg passed to MsBuild not recognized on PostBuildEvent

Tags: jenkins, msbuild, post-build-event

I have a csproj-file that I want to compile on my jenkins-server and that contains a postbuild-event:

```
<PostBuildEvent>
    IF NOT DEFINED AAACOPYNEWONLY GOTO :EOF

    IF "%25AAACOPYNEWONLY%25" == "yes" (
        SET NEWOPT=/D
    ) ELSE (
        SET NEWOPT=
        RMDIR /S /Q "$(Outdir)\..\schema"
    )

    XCOPY /E /Y /I /Q %25NEWOPT%25 $(ProjectDir)..\schema "$(Outdir)\..\Schema"
</PostBuildEvent>
```

when I define `AAACOPYNEWONLY` as system-environment-variable in windows everything works fine and the `schema`-folder is copied to whatever `ProjectDir` refers to.

But when I provide the variable directly within my call to msbuild the folder is not created:

```
msbuild MyProject.csproj -t:ReBuild -p:AAACOPYNEWONLY=NO
```

I also scanned my log-file, but there´s nothing that indicates xcopy even ran, which makes me assume that the condition `IF NOT DEFINED AAACOPYNEWONLY` does not match.

Why is the variable not appropriately passed into the event when provided as arg to msbuild?

EDIT: I simplified my postbuild a bit, to simply print the content of the variable:

```
<PostBuildEvent>
    echo AAACOPYNEWONLY = "%25AAACOPYNEWONLY%25"
</PostBuildEvent>
```

This simply prints `AAACOPYNEWONLY = ""`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define your property in `csproj` file in the same way with other MSBuild properties, like `Configuration` or `Platform`

```
<PropertyGroup>
...
   <AAACOPYNEWONLY Condition=" '$(AAACOPYNEWONLY)' == '' ">NO</AAACOPYNEWONLY>
...
</PropertyGroup>
```

Than you'll be able to pass it as parameter to msbuild command line, e.g. `-p:AAACOPYNEWONLY=NO` or `-p:AAACOPYNEWONLY=YES`

Comment: This way I also have to replace all references to the variable by something like `$(AAACOPYNEWONLY)`. Anyway good answer, didn´t know only variables defined in the file are valid as command-line args to msbuild.